# Discord.js V12 bot edits a role at intervals of 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to edit a role every 30 minutes. I was unsure how to do it so I looked at an another thread. Here is the code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
var colors = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9'];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");
    setInterval(() => {
        role.edit({
            color: colors[random]
        })
    }, 1800000);

})
```

I tried running this code however I get the following error:

```
(node:95) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined
(node:95) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:95) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can you help me out? Thanks In advance

Comment: Well, the ReferenceError is pretty clear -- message is undefined.  Are you expecting a global 'message' object to be available?  Is there some additional setup you could do to make sure it can be retrieved?  (I'm not a Discord guru, just know some js)

Answer (score 0):

In the [`Client#ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event there is no [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object by default, therefore you are not able to use the [`Message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) property.

Instead, you'll have to get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) from [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager). ([`Client#guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds))

---

## Discord JS v12:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID");

    if (!Guild) return console.error("Couldn't find the guild.");

    const Role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Admin");
    // You should really use the ES6 syntax for this.
    // Instead of: Guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");

    if (!Role) return console.error("Couldn't find the role.");

    // Your code here.
});
```

---

## Discord JS v11:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    const Guild = client.guilds.get("GuildID");

    if (!Guild) return console.error("Couldn't find the guild.");

    const Role = Guild.roles.find(role => role.name == "Admin");

    if (!Role) return console.error("Couldn't find the role.");
});
```

Comment: I think they might be using `v11` due to their outdated usage of `Collection.find()` and not using the `cache`

Comment: @Lioness100 Indeed, you are right. I'm going to update the code for v11 as soon as possible. Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem @Jakye :)